# Prolog: adding text to the end of a file

Tags: prolog

I want to add text to a database in prolog. Something like

```
adding :- tell('a.txt'), write('abc'), told.
```

but not overwriting the a.txt. I've tried using append like this:

```
append('a.txt'),write('abc'), told.
```

but it didn't work. The listener just give a 'no' response and file is not changed.
I'm using Amzi Prolog, btw.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Explain in detail what does "it didn't work" mean...

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. The listener just give 'no' response and the file a.txt didn't change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use these IO predicates: open/3, write/2, close/1.

```
adding :- open('a.txt', append, Handle), write(Handle, 'abc'), close(Handle).
```

Check [here](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_io.htm)

Comment: hey, thanks for the link. I've given it a try, and weirdly, it just print the 'abc' to the listener and not to the file. weird, logically what you stated should work.

Comment: @Hearty: Use write/2, that is write(Handle, 'abc') in your example.

Comment: ah, it works now. thank you. and @kaarel, thanks for you two's time. Really appreciated.

Comment: @Hearty you can thank everybody by upvoting their answers, and don't forget to mark one of the answers as "correct answer" if it solved your problem (in this case it would be gusbro's answer)

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog this works:

```
?- append('a.txt'), write('abc'), told.
true.

?- append('a.txt'), write('abc'), told.
true.
```

Maybe Amzi Prolog does not have `append/1` and this causes failure rather than an exception. Or maybe the file is not writable (and this causes failure, rather than an exception).

Comment: thanks. yes, I've debugged using Amzi and what you said seems true that it causes failure. Also, seen from this [link](http://forum.amzi.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=569) , it seems Amzi does have problem with append.

Comment: @Hearty this link discusses append/3 which is completely different from append/1